# Diff always fail to apply patch of files I make?

Tags: linux, patch-management, diff

I have some files in my server that I wanted to make a patch for, so I took one of the files to test:

```
cp /path/file ~/file
```

So now I have just the same file in my root directory so I make any changes I need on the file at ~/file and now I run the diff command on the 2 files:

```
diff -Nuar /path/file ~/file > my_file.patch
```

I have also tried:

```
diff -u /path/file ~/file > my_file.patch
diff -c /path/file ~/file > my_file.patch
diff /path/file ~/file > my_file.patch
```

Now as you can see there is no differences on the files besides what I have just changed on it but instead of creating a my_file.patch with only the code to patch the changes I made into /path/file it always create a full file with all the content of /path/file marked to be removed and the content of ~/file marked to be added.

Then I try to apply the patch:

```
patch -p0 < ~/my_file.patch
```

And it fails badly ... it always print out a reject file with all the content just like the file is.

I am running out of ideas to why it is doing this all the time, with a few files I can produce a patch without problems but with most of the files on the system that I need to make one it won't work at all.

Any ideas on what could be the problem ? encoding, format ? solutions ?

Comment: Is it possible that some of the files have Windows (DOS) line endings instead of Unix newlines? Try running `dos2unix` on them before doing the `diff`.

Comment: You might also cut and paste the first few header lines of the patch file here, minus the actual data for us to look at.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson indeed the files seemed to be in dos format so on the linux i had to run fromdos < /path/file > /path/file.unix inst there a better way to accomplish this ? I dont want to have to do this with all the 10k files and then rename it all back.

Comment: I will post my suggestion as an answer along with an answer to the question in your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that some of the files have Windows (DOS) line endings instead of Unix newlines? Try running `dos2unix` on them before doing the `diff`.

Both `dos2unix` and `fromdos` (on my system, the former is a symlink to the latter) accept filenames on the command line and do the conversion in place. You can use the `-b` option to have it make a backup. If you have a lot of these files in various directories, you can use `find` to process them.

```
find /dir/to/start -type f -name "foo*" -exec fromdos -b {} +
```

Then when you're satisfied that all went well:

```
find /dir/to/start -type f -name "foo*.bak"  -delete
```

to delete the backups.

Comment: sounds like a plan thanks, is there a way to define a default output folder for -b as well ?

Comment: @Prix: The backup files will be output in the same directory where the file is.

Answer (score 0):

`patch` is very sensitive to its current directory and to the `-p` option. Are you certain that you are attempting to apply the patch from the correct location? Are you specifying a prefix (via `-p`) that is appropriate to the contents of your patch file?

Comment: yes I am sure it is an issue with the files itself like Dennis spotted on the comments, I have also created files to test it to make sure just in case.